# Getting ip address of visitors visiting sharepoint SharePoint online home page

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to get IP addresses of visitors visiting SharePoint online home page? What are the different ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could put a CEWP on a home page and get the IP on page load using javascript, as it does here: http://net.ipcalf.com.

Then store it in some custom List using CSOM.

Unless user's browser blocks your script.